# Rollup generates (node-resolve plugin) TypeError: Cannot read property 'preserveSymlinks' of undefined Error

Tags: rollupjs

I am using rollup for bundling and getting the following error

```
[!] (node-resolve plugin) TypeError: Cannot read property 'preserveSymlinks' of undefined
```

I am attaching rollup configuration

```
// rollup.config.js
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import nodeResolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import replace from "rollup-plugin-replace";

export default {
    input: 'src/sdk.js',
    output: [
        { file: './dist/sdk.iife.js', format: 'iife' },
        { file: './dist/sdk.min.js', format: 'cjs' },
        { file: './dist/sdk.esm.js', format: 'es' }
    ],
    plugins: [

        nodeResolve({
            jsnext: true,
            main: true,
            browser: true,
            preferBuiltins: true
        }),
        babel(),
        commonjs({
            include: /node_modules/
        }),
        terser({
            include: [/^.+\.min\.js$/, '*esm*'],
            exclude: ['some*'],
            compress: {
                drop_console: true
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

I have installed rollup and all dependencies as per the rollup configuration mentioned in the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The issue was I have installed `rollup` globally and dependencies like `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` installed locally for the project.

That caused the error.

Solution: Install **rollup locally in the project folder** solved my issue.

```
npm install rollup --save
```

instead of `npm install rollup --global`